# Android Studio - Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio

I'm facing this issue when i'm trying to run the project.
Project cleans successfully, but when i tried to rebuild the project, it gives me following errors(see attached image).
Below is my app level and project level build.gradle files.
Can anybody help me?

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 27

buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pckg.appname"

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
                   minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../libs']
      }
  }
}

 configurations {

    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  }


dependencies {

     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',

   {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

compile 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'

compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'

compile 'com.github.florent37:bubbletab:1.0.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'

compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

compile 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.2'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'

compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.aromajoin.library:actionsheet:0.0.1'

compile 'com.github.devlight.pulseview:library:1.0.2'

compile 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'

// compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.0"

compile 'com.github.karanchuri:PermissionManager:0.1.0'

compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.17.0'

implementation "com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8"

implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:1.3.9'

compile 'com.github.iammert:ExpandableLayout:1.3'

compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.1.1'

compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

// compile group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.17.1"

/*compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.17.0'

compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.17.0'*/

compile 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.17'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (Project:appname)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
   all sub-projects/modules.
   buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
   }
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/gigamole/maven/'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
     }
   }
 }
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }


dependencies {
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Use `./gradlew app:dependencies` to find out where the class HttpRequestBase is provided from multiple times

Comment: where should i add this line?

Comment: in gradle console